# Convert long java datetime to SQL Server datetime

Tags: sql-server, datetime

I have `1579537505834` long , representing a date & time of `2020-01-20 17:25:05.833`.

I try to convert it to a `datetime` value for SQL Server:

```
select 
    convert(datetime, (((1579537505834) / (1000.0 * 60.0 * 60.0 * 24.0)) +  25567))
```

But the result is: `2020-01-20 16:25:05.833`: 1 hour of error.

Thanks

EDIT: the problem is +1 TIME ZONE! how can I do?

EDIT2: with PostgreSQL, I don't have this problem

```
SELECT to_timestamp (1579537505834 / 1000)
```

EDIT3:
The solution

```
select convert(datetime,(((cast(1579537505834 as bigint)) / (1000.0 * 60.0 * 60.0 * 24.0)) + 25567 ))+cast(DateDiff(Hour, GetUTCDate(), GetDate()) as numeric(35,15))/24
```

WORK! THANKS TO ALL!

Comment: Online converter converts this digit to 16:25 as well. Are you sure it is 17:25?

Comment: yes, enough, but I do some tests again ..
Does the conversion function in sqlserver seem right?

Comment: The problem is add the time zone:

GMT: Monday 20 January 2020 16:25:05.834


Your time zone: lunedì 20 gennaio 2020 17:25:05.834 GMT+01:00

Comment: Could daylight savings and/or time zones be causing this problem?

Comment: yes George. I see now.

Comment: The simplest way is to add one hour: `select convert(datetime,(((cast(1579537505834 as bigint)) / (1000.0 * 60.0 * 60.0 * 24.0)) + 25567 ))+cast(1 as numeric(35,15))/24`.

Comment: I don't know if this helps, but you can get the timezone offset with this:  Select DateDiff(Hour, GetUTCDate(), GetDate())

Comment: You can simplify your syntax a little. `SELECT DATEADD(SECOND,(1579537505834 / 1000.0), '01/01/1970')`

Comment: @ChrisAlbert, this approach misses milliseconds.

Comment: According to @GeorgeMastros advice, you can use this: `select convert(datetime,(((cast(1579537505834 as bigint)) / (1000.0 * 60.0 * 60.0 * 24.0)) + 25567 ))+cast(DateDiff(Hour, GetUTCDate(), GetDate()) as numeric(35,15))/24`.

Comment: *with Postgress i don't have this problem* - Here https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=e8f11178d0c5dd2db9566be191a4a291 16:25 as well.

Comment: @Максим Золотенко in my postgress work (postgress 11)

Answer (score 0):

AT TIMEZONE can switch the TIMEZONE (this is the ISO SQL standard operator) :

```
SELECT CONVERT(datetime, (((1579537505834) / (1000.0 * 60.0 * 60.0 * 24.0)) +  25567)) AT TIME ZONE 'GREENWICH STANDARD TIME' AT TIME ZONE  'CENTRAL EUROPEAN STANDARD TIME'
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way of calculating the new date which I think, will be quicker, but loose ms is :

```
SELECT DATEADD(s, 1579537505834.0 / 1000, '1970-01-01')
```

Can replace the

```
CONVERT(datetime, (((1579537505834) / (1000.0 * 60.0 * 60.0 * 24.0)) +  25567))
```

Comment: i try (SELECT DATEADD(s, 1579594224900 / 1000, '1970-01-01'))
the date is 2020-01-21 09:10:24.000, but the result is 2020-01-21 08:10:24.000

Comment: view EDIT3 please. Thank so much!